# Изменение репутации на +-100

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, репутация, уведомления

Раньше об уменьшенной репутации вроде как не уведомляли, а сейчас уведомили слишком странно)

[image]

Comment: Всегда уведомляли )

Comment: @Suvitruf ну раньше я всяких +-1 не видел

Comment: @andreymal, ну меня про -100 не уведомили сегодня.

Comment: @Suvitruf, неа, никогда не видел.

Comment: @Qwertiy странно о_О

Comment: Возможно, ты словил минус на странице, где уже показывалась плашка с плюсом?

Comment: @Qwertiy не знаю, я тут где-то час не заходил на ruSO, сейчас зашёл — а тут такое. Кроме этого я сегодня лишь два минуса ставил сообщениям низкого качества, при этом об этих минусах уведомления не было

Comment: А я вот [вопрос задал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/994872/178988) - вижу, на нём плюсы есть, а уведомления никакого нет - полез смотреть - а внутри минус.

Comment: Хм.. Это же конкурс, а не просто минус...

Comment: Нужны красные круги на картинках. Мне кажется, многие просто не понимают о чем речь.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ я только после ответа default locale понял, о чём речь :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Исправлено. [@Brian Nickel♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/235711/brian-nickel) пишет на Meta.SE ([Positive AND Negative reputation show as +-1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329827)):

> This is building out right now.
>
> I had to tweak the code to pass a number around instead of a string, and I mistakenly replaced rep.IsNullOrEmpty() with rep == 0 instead of rep <= 0.

Comment: Выглядит так, будто там никаких юнит тестов нет)

Comment: @Suvitruf зачем? у них MDD: meta-driven development :)